# work through a file in python

Tags: python, dns

I am new to python and with this task I'm trying to learn it. I'd like to get information out of a DNS zone file. The DNS file has the following entries:

```
something 600 A 192.168.123.45
          600 A 192.168.123.46
someelse CNAME something
anotherone A 192.168.123.47
nextone CNAME anotherone
anotherone TXT ( "te asd as as d" )
```

The goal is to grab the hostnames and IF there is a coresponding TXT entry, I'd like to get the information for that entry as well.

So I started to just work through the file, if I would describe the entries, the Record type is either at [2] or [1] and right after it, I got the IP. So I have something like this for now:

```
for line in data:
    word = line.split() 
    if len(word) > 2:
        if "CNAME" == word[2]:
            rectype = "CNAME"
             arecord = word[3].replace('.domain.com.', '')
            print rectype + " " + arecord
        if "CNAME" == word[1]:
            rectype = "CNAME"
             arecord = word[2].replace('.domain.com.', '')
            print rectype + " " + arecord
        if "A" == word[2]:
            rectype = "A"
            print rectype + " " + word[3]
        if "A" == word[1]:
            rectype = "A"
            print rectype + " " + word[2]
```

okay, so far so good.. but now if I like to get that corresponding TXT record, do I need to work through every line in the document for each line or is their any easier and more efficiernt way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the beauty of Python is you can write code that reads like English and it uses intuitive operators.

You have a **lot** of duplicated code. In your example, we can see that anytime a "keyword" pops up, such as `A` or `CNAME` then you simply take the next token. Here, I used the `in` Python keyword which checks if an element is in a collection of some sort. This is a boolean, so if it returns true then I take the next element, ie, `tokens[tokens.index(keyword) + 1]`.

Similarly, `in` can also be used for string and substring searches. I check to see if "TXT" is in the current line, and if it is, I assume you want everything after it? I use a splice operator to specify the range.
`line[line.index("TXT") + 3:]` means that I want everything in line **after** the index `line.index("TXT") + 3`.

```
KEYWORDS = ["CNAME", "A"]

for line in data:
    tokens = line.split()
    if len(tokens) > 2:
        record = ""
        for keyword in KEYWORDS:
            if keyword in tokens:
                record = keyword + " " + tokens[tokens.index(keyword) + 1]

        if "TXT" in line:
            txt_data = line[line.index("TXT") + 3:]
            record += "TXT: " + txt_data

        print record
```

Comment: I already thought that all these if's could have been made more elegant, but I wanted to have some results first. But put putting both strings into keywords and then ask for keywords in KEYWORDS is really nice. Do I really need the zonefile.split()? I mean isn't doing for line in zonefile kinda the same anyway?                About the TXT, I think I cannot trust that the TXT is somewhere a few lines before or after, I have to find the matching TXT entry no matter where in the file it is.

Comment: Please provide an example which covers the different use for the TXT entry then.

And ignore the zonefile split. I copied-pasted your data into a long string and needed a way to go through it. Will be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you build a dictionary whose keys are identifiers ("anotherone" would be an example from your sample) and whose values are strings (or maybe a list of strings - I'm rusty on DNS and am not sure if multiples are possible).

As you encounter CNAME and A records, add the identifiers as keys into the dictionary and initialize their corresponding values as empty lists.  Then when you hit a line with "TXT" in it, lookup that identifier in the dictionary and add the line as value.